# Sourcecode on the left, Nassi–Shneiderman on the right (float?)

Tags: listings, positioning, diagrams, struktex

I’d like to place a Nassi-Schneiderman diagram into my LaTeX document but also to have the source code for the shown algorithm beside it. Drawing the diagram worked just fine using the `StrukTeX`package, showing the source code isn’t a problem either.

The problem is: I can’t think of a way to have text (or in this case: the sourcecode) on the left and the diagram on the right (or vice versa). How do I solve this?

Here is the part of my code that is necessary for this question:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german,curves]{struktex}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\lstset{
        basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
        numbers=left,               % Ort der Zeilennummern
        numberstyle=\tiny,          % Stil der Zeilennummern
        numbersep=5pt,              % Abstand der Nummern zum Text
        tabsize=3,                  %
        extendedchars=true,         %
        breaklines=true,            %
        keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf,
        commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
        frame=bottomline,
         stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry}\ttfamily, % Farbe der String
         xleftmargin=17pt,
         framexleftmargin=17pt,
         framexrightmargin=5pt,
         framexbottommargin=4pt,    
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
int eingabe = 13;
    int vrbeingabe = eingabe;
    String ergebnis = "";

    while(vrbeingabe > 0) {
        if(vrbeingabe % 2 == 0) {
            ergebnis = ("0"+ergebnis);
            vrbeingabe = vrbeingabe / 2;
        } else {
            ergebnis = ("1"+ergebnis);
            vrbeingabe = vrbeingabe / 2;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Die Dezimalzahl "+eingabe+" entspricht der Binaerzahl "+ergebnis);
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{struktogramm}(85,20)[Umwandlung dezimaler in binäre Zahlen]
    \assign[10]{Eingabe $i$}
    \assign[10]{bs $\gets \emptyset$}
    \while[8]{solang $i > 0$}
        \ifthenelse[15]{5}{6}
            {Rest bei $\frac{i}{2}$}{\sTrue}{\sFalse}
            \assign{bs $\gets$ "1" $+$ bs}
        \change
            \assign{bs $\gets$ "0" $+$ bs}
        \ifend
                   \assign{i $\gets \frac{i}{2}$}
               \whileend
    \assign[10]{Ausgabe bs}
\end{struktogramm}
\end{document}
```

So far, the output looks like this:
[image: output-of-code-above]

With the minipage environment suggested in one of the answers, it looks like this:
[image: minipage]

EDIT: Added the actual part of the code. Sorry for the inconvenience of my bad example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two side-by-side `minipage`s: (perhaps you'll need to adjust some settings):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german,curves]{struktex}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}

\lstset{
        basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
        numbers=left,               % Ort der Zeilennummern
        numberstyle=\tiny,          % Stil der Zeilennummern
        numbersep=5pt,              % Abstand der Nummern zum Text
        tabsize=3,                  %
        extendedchars=true,         %
        breaklines=true,            %
        keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf,
        commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
        frame=bottomline,
         stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry}\ttfamily, % Farbe der String
         xleftmargin=17pt,
         framexleftmargin=17pt,
         framexrightmargin=5pt,
         framexbottommargin=4pt,    
 }

\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}% uncomment this, and the corresponding \end{figure} below 
%if you want to turn the object into a floating one; in this case, the 
%following \noindent is superfluous
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace*{0pt}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,framexrightmargin=0pt]
int eingabe = 13;
    int vrbeingabe = eingabe;
    String ergebnis = "";

    while(vrbeingabe > 0) {
        if(vrbeingabe % 2 == 0) {
            ergebnis = ("0"+ergebnis);
            vrbeingabe = vrbeingabe / 2;
        } else {
            ergebnis = ("1"+ergebnis);
            vrbeingabe = vrbeingabe / 2;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Die Dezimalzahl "+eingabe+" entspricht der Binaerzahl "+ergebnis);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace*{0pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{struktogramm}(60,20)[Umwandlung dezimaler in binäre Zahlen]
    \assign[10]{Eingabe $i$}
    \assign[10]{bs $\gets \emptyset$}
    \while[8]{solang $i > 0$}
        \ifthenelse[15]{5}{6}
            {Rest bei $\frac{i}{2}$}{\sTrue}{\sFalse}
            \assign{bs $\gets$ "1" $+$ bs}
        \change
            \assign{bs $\gets$ "0" $+$ bs}
        \ifend
                   \assign{i $\gets \frac{i}{2}$}
               \whileend
    \assign[10]{Ausgabe bs}
\end{struktogramm}
\end{minipage}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does work but, as you said, there seem to be some settings I might have to adjust. Just as in your picture, the left minipage doesn’t start on par with the right one. As I haven’t set anything that would change the margin to the top, I’m wondering where this stems from.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu this is controlled by the optional argument of `minipage`; now I've updated my answer with the default vertical alignment.

Comment: Having transferred the changes you made to my document, the code is now on top of the page, but the diagram isn’t anymore (I changed the code section to the actual code). It starts when the code is about halfway through.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu please add some code to your original question reproducing the problem mentioned; otherwise, all I can do is to guess, and that's not the right way to proceed.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience; I changed it and also added a screenshot of the output with your code.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu No problem. I updated my answer; please let me know of this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This almost does what I intended to do, yes. I will have to change some minor details, but I guess I can figure them out myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Consider using [`wrapfig`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package:</strike>

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{struktogramm}(85,20)[Umwandlung dezimaler in binäre Zahlen]
        ...
    \end{struktogramm}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

That would place you diagramm on the right. And, obviously, text on the left.

It's possible to wrap into `wrapfigure` code:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
    // Java Code
    // to be on the left/right
    // of the Nassi-Shneiderman
    //diagramm
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

That would place the `struktogramm` on the left and code on the right.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn’t seem to work with `\begin{struktogramm}…\end{struktogramm}`

Comment: The second attempt doesn’t work either. Here is a [picture](http://imgur.com/BhQy9)